# Является ли строка словом

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как написать метод, который проверяет, что введенная строка является словом, а не числом?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Введите название столицы Китая: ");
    try {
        String city = in.nextLine();
        if(city.equals("Пекин")){
            System.out.println("Правильно, столица Китая " + city);
        }else {
            System.out.println("Неправильно");
        }
    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: В данном случае это всё равно ни на что не повлияет. Зачем вам это проверять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Проверка
        System.out.println(isWord("100")); // false
        System.out.println(isWord("Привет")); // true
        System.out.println(isWord("мир")); // true
        System.out.println(isWord("!")); // false
        System.out.println(isWord("15Hello")); // false
        System.out.println(isWord("world")); // true
        System.out.println(isWord("world!")); // false
}
    
private static boolean isWord(String str) {
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
        if(!Character.isUpperCase(Character.toUpperCase(c)))
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо!